# User accounts authentication from Active Directory

Tags: windows, active-directory

I'm looking into Active Directory user account authentications.The situation is like this.I have a Forest DC at data centre 1, and infrastructure child DC at some site.

I want the infrastructure servers administrative user accounts authenticated from the Forest DC, and the other user accounts at the site to be authenticated from the infrastructure child DC at the site.

My question is, is this a good approach, or it is better to have all accounts authenticated at the Forest DC.

The advantage I see with my approach is that in case WAN is down, the infrastructure child DC will be able to authenticate the local user accounts. In case all accounts are authenticated at Forest DC and WAN is down the accounts cannot be authenticated at all, unless I have AD replication of Forest DC at the site ?

Or is it that once the infrastructure child DC join the Forest they will have AD replication automatically ?

Could someone elaborate on this approach.

Thank You

Comment: If you want to make it such that the forest users can be authenticated at any site when the WAN link is down you either need to 1) allow for cached logons (which I am against - especially for administrative accounts), and/or 2) provide a DC for each domain in each site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users authenticate to Domain Controllers in the domain to which they belong.

The Domain partition does not replicate to other domains in the Forest. Attributes marked for Global Catalog replication will replicate to all Global Catalog servers in the Forest, but user and computer accounts in the Domain partition do not replicate to other domains in the Forest.

Comment: I believe I might not be clear enough.

I have a forest DC a.local, 3 child dcs (b.a.local, c.a.local, d.a.local) in the same forest and same site.

I want to have the child DCs authenticate from the Forest DC (main DC), and the clients to authenticate from the child DC because as I see if all authentication is done at forest DC and WAN is down then the clients AND child DCs wont be able to authenticate.

My question is is this a good approach, unlike where all end clients, and child DCs authenticate from the Forest DC due to the reason given above.